# Upgrade to Radeon 7900XT Hangs Boot Process

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, freeze, radeon

I am running an RX 580 on 22.10 with the 6.1.0 kernel. I bought a new RX 7900XT but my computer will not boot normally with it installed.

It hangs right after the terminal output but before the Ubuntu logo with spinner. The terminal output is the same as with the working RX580.

I can get to desktop under recovery mode but not using the Radeon drivers I installed from AMD's website.

From what I've read, it should just work out of the box,

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: You need to install newer firmware from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

Comment: That worked - needed the latest firmware not from apt